# how to insert timeuuid into cassandra using datastax java driver OR Invalid version for TimeUUID

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, datastax

I have one column in the cassandra keyspace that is of type timeuuid. When I try to insert a reocord from the java code (using DataStax java driver1.0.3). I get the following exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid version for TimeUUID type.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(ResultSetFuture.java:269)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(ResultSetFuture.java:183)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:111)
```

**Here is my sample code:**

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO keyspace:table " +
            "(id, subscriber_id, transaction_id) VALUES (now(), ?, ?);");

BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);

Session.execute(boundStatement.bind(UUID.fromString(requestData.getsubscriberId()), 
            requestData.getTxnId()));
```

I have also tried to use `UUIDs.timeBased()` instead of `now()`. But I am gettting the same exception.

Any help on how to insert/read from `timeuuid` datatype would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By mistake I had created

```
id  uuid
```

That is why when I try to insert `timeuuid` in the `uuid` type field I was getting that exception.

Now I have changed the type for id to timeuuid and everything is working fine.